# RStudio create environment to store variable values during debug

Tags: r, debugging, environment-variables

I am debugging a function in RStudio that is used inside of a loop. I am using browser() right before calling it in each iteration and I would would like to compare the input arguments (and potentially use the arguments from iterations where the error doesn't occur) but i don't know how to store the arguments from the previous iteration. Below is an example code (which doesn't work, because e1 does not exist anymore in the next iteration):

```
for (i in steps){
  browser()
e1 <- rlang::global_env()
e1$prev_arg1 <- arg1
e1$prev_arg2 <- arg2
  erroneous_function(arg1, arg2)

}
```

Comment: Or should I just save them to an external R file? CSV?

Comment: Move `e1 <- rlang::global_env()` to before the `for()` loop so you don't re-define it every iteration.

Comment: So it actually isn't in the loop, I am just running it from the console after the browser(). Also, the args are changing in the loop, so I have to keep it in there somehow. But you are saying to create it before the loop starts? And then fill it with values inside of the loop?